# How to set up generic owl object relationships

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, owl, description-logic

Warning: newbie question.

I am trying to model (as a simplified example) dogs with an associated numerical value for a set of classes associated with a dog, such as "fluffiness". I'm confused about how to represent a specific type (e.g. Dog) taking on a specific numerical value with respect to another type (e.g. Fluffiness). For example:

```
:Dog rdf:type owl:Class .
:Fluffiness rdf:type owl:Class .
:describedBy rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty ;
             rdfs:domain :Dog ;
             rdfs:range :Fluffiness .
:hasValue rdf:type owl:DatatypeProperty ;
          rdfs:domain :Fluffiness ;
          rdfs:range :&xsd;float .

:Chihuahua rdf:type :Dog .
```

How do I associate the Chihuahua with the specific value of, say 0.1, of a generic property of dog, such as Fluffiness? And is there a way to do it without resorting to just dropping Fluffiness as a class and defining a "hasFluffiness" Datatype property?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the moment, your representation works, but it's a little bit convoluted, in my opinion.  You end up with instance data like:

```
Chihuahua describedBy fluffiness72 .
fluffiness72 hasValue 4.
```

As you note, you could instead have a hasFluffiness datatype property, but if you don't want to do that, I think your best bet here is to have an **Attribute** class of which things like **Fluffiness**, **Size**, **Friendliness**, etc., are instances.  Then, you can have an **AttributeValue** class and properties **attribute** and **value** (you can probably come up with better names), so that you write data like this:

```
:chihuahua62 rdf:type :Chihuahua ;
             :hasAttributeValue [ :attribute :Fluffiness   ; :value 3 ] ;
             :hasAttributeValue [ :attribute :Friendliness ; :value 2 ] .
```

With this kind of representation, you can say things like "every chihuahua has a fluffiness level less than 4":

> ((∃hasAttributeValue<sup>-1</sup>.Chihuahua) ⊓ (=attribute.Fluffiness)) ⊑ ∀value.xsd:float[≤4.0]
>
> ((**inverse**(hasAttributeValue) **some** Chihuahua) **and** (attribute **value** Fluffiness)) **SubClassOf** (value **only** xsd:float[<= 4.0])

In English, that says that every **AttributeValue** for a Chihuahua that's for the attribute **Fluffiness** must have a value less than 4.0.

You could use an alternative representation that says "if a Chihuahua has an attribute value, then *if* the attribute is Fluffiness, then then the value is less than 4.0".  That's equivalent to "if a Chihuahua has an attribute value, then either the attribute is *not* Fluffiness, or the value is less than 4.0":

> Chihuahua ⊑ ∀hasAttributeValue.(¬(=attribute.Fluffiness) ⊔ (∀value.xsd:float[≤4.0]))

That's easier to write into an ontology editor, since it's a subclass axiom about a class that you're interested in.

Here's an ontology that shows both approaches:

```
@prefix :      <http://stackoverflow.com/q/24760392/1281433/dogProperties#> .
@prefix owl:   <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix rdf:   <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix xsd:   <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix rdfs:  <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .

:Shagginess  a  owl:NamedIndividual , :Attribute .

:hasValue  a         owl:DatatypeProperty ;
        rdfs:domain  :_attVal .

[ a                   owl:Class ;
  rdfs:subClassOf     [ a                  owl:Restriction ;
                        owl:allValuesFrom  [ a                     rdfs:Datatype ;
                                             owl:onDatatype        xsd:float ;
                                             owl:withRestrictions  ( [ xsd:minInclusive
                                                               10 ] )
                                           ] ;
                        owl:onProperty     :hasValue
                      ] ;
  owl:intersectionOf  ( [ a                   owl:Restriction ;
                          owl:onProperty      [ owl:inverseOf  :hasAttributeValue ] ;
                          owl:someValuesFrom  :Newfoundland
                        ] [ a               owl:Restriction ;
                            owl:hasValue    :Shagginess ;
                            owl:onProperty  :hasAttribute
                          ] )
] .

:Newfoundland  a         owl:Class ;
        rdfs:subClassOf  :Dog .

:Attribute  a   owl:Class .

:_attVal  a     owl:Class .

:hasAttribute  a     owl:ObjectProperty ;
        rdfs:domain  :_attVal ;
        rdfs:range   :Attribute .

:Chihuahua  a            owl:Class ;
        rdfs:subClassOf  :Dog ;
        rdfs:subClassOf  [ a                  owl:Restriction ;
                           owl:allValuesFrom  [ a            owl:Class ;
                                                owl:unionOf  ( [ a                 owl:Class ;
                                                                 owl:complementOf  [ a               owl:Restriction ;
                                                                                     owl:hasValue    :Shagginess ;
                                                                                     owl:onProperty  :hasAttribute
                                                                                   ]
                                                               ] [ a                  owl:Restriction ;
                                                                   owl:allValuesFrom  [ a                     rdfs:Datatype ;
                                                                                        owl:onDatatype        xsd:float ;
                                                                                        owl:withRestrictions  ( [ xsd:maxInclusive
                                                                                                          4 ] )
                                                                                      ] ;
                                                                   owl:onProperty     :hasValue
                                                                 ] )
                                              ] ;
                           owl:onProperty     :hasAttributeValue
                         ] .

:hasAttributeValue  a  owl:ObjectProperty ;
        rdfs:range  :_attVal .

:Dog    a       owl:Class .

<http://stackoverflow.com/q/24760392/1281433/dogProperties>
        a       owl:Ontology .
```

Comment: Thanks! It looks like the first approach is what I'm after - instead of having to create specific instances for every attribute/value combination, I can use a blank node to specify some instance of Fluffiness associated with an instance of a dog and a value associated with that Attribute instance.

Comment: The first and second approaches I mentioned (after describing what your current approach is like) are the same;  they difference is just in the way that I wrote the axiom.  In both cases, the idea is to use an auxiliary individual as a n-ary relation that links to the dog, the attribute, and the value.  I'm glad it looks like it's working for you!